# Why Header set will not replace the previous header in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control

To prevent 404 error being cached for a long time, I set the TTL for 404 to 3 minutes in .htaccess, as below:

```
#  Set Cache-Control, CDN-Cache-Control and Cloudflare-CDN-Cache-Control for 404 not found error
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=180, must-revalidate" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"
Header set CDN-Cache-Control "max-age=180, must-revalidate" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"
Header set Cloudflare-CDN-Cache-Control "max-age=180, must-revalidate" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"
```

Based on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html, **"The response header is set, replacing any previous header with this name."**.

However, the actual result is that when I access an unexisting page in my website, such as http://www.sybase-recovery.com/my-not-found1, the response will contains two Cache-Control headers, as below:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Where is the other Cache-Control header coming from?   Maybe something else is adding the second one after .htaccess?